# Can't find RPG Session, were can i look for one?

Tags: social

I can't find an RPG or table top session were I am, Are there any good resources to find one?

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! We manage duplicates this way so that answers all stay in one place and it's easier for folks to find them. If you're facing a challenge not addressed by the question this has been closed as a duplicate of, please [edit] this question to focus on that, or ask a new question.

Comment: Duplicates aren't bad! They're actually useful, because they give people searching for information multiple ways to find the answers. So that it can help future searchers, I've undeleted this question. Cheers!